# drawRect Android Canvas

Tags: android

Não consigo entender como funciona o **canvas.drawRect** no android.

**canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint)**

Eu "venho" do canvas do HTML5 que seria.

**(contexto).fillRect(posiçãoX, posiçãoY, largura, altura)**

A dúvida é eu queria saber como determinar **posição X, posição Y, largura, altura** do retângulo no canvas do android ?

Comment: da uma olhada developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html esta explicando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caro, para utilizar a função `canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint)` você deve considerar o seguinte:

- **left:** coordenada **x** do canto superior esquerdo do retângulo;
- **top:** coordenada **y** do canto superior esquerdo do retângulo;
- **right:** coordenada **x** do canto inferior direito do retângulo;
- **bottom:** coordenada **y** do canto inferior direito do retângulo;
- **paint:** objeto Paint que determina as características do seu retângulo, como por exemplo a cor.

Lembrando que você deve ter em mente o [sistema de coordenadas do Java](http://www.webbasedprogramming.com/Java-Unleashed-Second-Edition/f19-2.gif) em relação à View onde você irá desenhar seu retângulo.

Então se você quiser desenhar um retângulo que comece nas coordenadas x=100 e y=100 e tenha largura de 400 e altura de 900 você pode utilizar a seguinte chamada:

```
...
canvas.drawRect(100f, 100f, 500f, 1000f, paint);
...
```

Não sei exatamente onde e como você vai utilizar isso, mas abaixo segue um exemplo bem simples que você pode rodar e fazer alguns testes.

- activity_main.xml

  ```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/resulting_image"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="2"/>

  <Button android:id="@+id/btn_create_square"
      android:text="Create Square"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  ```
- MainActivity.java

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.resulting_image);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_create_square);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createSquare();
            }
        });
    }

    //Este é o método que efetivamente desenha o retângulo
    private void createSquare() {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageView.getWidth(),
                mImageView.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        //configuracao do obj Paint com as características do retângulo
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        //desenhando...
        canvas.drawRect(100f, 100f, 500f, 1000f, paint);

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

- Resultado:

[image: Desenhando um retângulo simples em uma ImageView]

Espero que ajude!